# Back pressed in fragment runs function in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity that calls a fragment as seen below:

Nav drawer in main activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if(id == R.id.nav_jobs_layout){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new JobsFragment())
                .addToBackStack("Jobs")
                .commit();
    }else if(id == R.id.nav_shipments_out){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ShipmentsOutFragment())
                .addToBackStack("ShipmentsOut")
                .commit();
    }else if(id == R.id.logout){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Authentication auth = new Authentication(preferences);
        auth.logout();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When I click shipments it opens my shipments fragment, in there I have a list of shipments for the user to choose from. On choice I open another fragment which will display there. This is done here:

ShipmentFragment:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Shipment shipment = shipments.get(position);

        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        ShipmentsOutDetailsFragment newFragment = new ShipmentsOutDetailsFragment();

        newFragment.shipment = shipment;

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
                .addToBackStack("Shipments")
                .commit();
    }
});
```

On this next fragment I am showing the details of the shipment that was chosen. The issue comes when you click back on that fragment. As when that first fragment is loaded each time I reload the base shipments.

When you click back it seems to run the onBackPressed function as seen here which is in the main activity. How can I stop this from being run? Is there an override I can put into either of the fragments?

Here is that annoying onBackPressed that is in the main activity, I DONT want this to run when I click back on the secondary fragment but on the first one I do.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Log.v("BackPressed", "This function has been run");

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follow

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (count == 0) {
                super.onBackPressed(); //this method just will be called when there is none more fragments
            } else getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Abner you sir are a genius

Answer (score 1):

You can declare two feilds :

```
 final static int JOBS_FRAGMENT = 0;
 final static int SHIPMENTS_OUT_FRAGMENT = 1;
```

And another `variable` where you can save the current `fragment` shown :

```
 public int currentFragmentShown = JOBS_FRAGMENT; // Or add the fragment shown by default on the start of the activity
```

Then change the value of `currentFragmentShwon` each time the `fragment` is changed :

```
    if(id == R.id.nav_jobs_layout){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new JobsFragment())
                .addToBackStack("Jobs")
                .commit();
        currentFragmentShown = JOBS_FRAGMENT;
    }else if(id == R.id.nav_shipments_out){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ShipmentsOutFragment())
                .addToBackStack("ShipmentsOut")
                .commit();
        currentFragmentShown = SHIPMENTS_OUT_FRAGMENT;
    }
```

Then inide `onBackPressed()` function you can do like follow :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

 if (currentFragmentShown == JOBS_FRAGMENT) {
        //Do whatever you want to do when jobs fragment is shown
    } else {
        //Do whatever you want to do when shippement out fragment fragment is shown
    }
}
```

This maybe not the best solution, but i hope this can help

Comment: Looks like it would do the trick but Abners post does that in a far simpler way